Convergence of a complex series $ f(z) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{z^n}{n^2}$ on the unit circle $|z| = 1$
Consider the series
$
f(z) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{z^n}{n^2} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(x + jy)^n}{n^2} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{r^n e^{jn\theta}}{n^2} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{r^n (\cos(n\theta) + j \sin(n\theta))}{n^2}
$
where we rewrite it as
$
f(z) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{r^n \cos(n\theta)}{n^2} + j \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{r^n \sin(n\theta)}{n^2}.
$
The radius of convergence of this series is $1$, so if $r > 1$, the series diverges.
However, it appears that if we set $ r = 1 $, the function $f(z)$ remains finite for every $ |z| = 1 $. This seems to imply that there is no singularity on the unit circle $ |z| = 1 $.
To explore this, note that we can bound the magnitude of the series ( S ) as follows:
$
|S| = \left| \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(n\theta)}{n^2} + j \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(n\theta)}{n^2} \right| \leq \left| \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(n\theta)}{n^2} \right| + \left| \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(n\theta)}{n^2} \right| = S_1 + S_2.
$
Next, consider the bounds on $ S_1 $ and $ S_2 $:
$
S_1 = \left| \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(n\theta)}{n^2} \right| \leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left| \frac{\cos(n\theta)}{n^2} \right| \leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{6},
$
and similarly,
$
S_2 = \left| \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(n\theta)}{n^2} \right| \leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left| \frac{\sin(n\theta)}{n^2} \right| \leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{6}.
$
Thus,
$
|S| = S_1 + S_2 \leq \frac{\pi^2}{3}.
$
Now to conclude, does this argument correctly show that $ f(z) $ is finite on the unit circle $ |z| = 1 $? If so, does this imply that the series does not have any singularity on $ |z| = 1 $, even though $|z| = 1 $ is the boundary of its convergence radius?

The series is absolutely convergent on the unit circle by M-Test (which is valid for complex series also). No need to consider real and imaginary parts.

As mentioned in the comment, you are essentially using the M-test to show that the series converges uniformly over the closed disc $\overline{D}$. This means the function can be defined as a continuous function over $\overline{D}$.
But it can also be shown that the radius of convergence is exactly $1$, hence there must be at least one singularity on the boundary.
There is no contradiction. We do have the classification of isolated singularity, and if the function can be continuously extended to the isolated singularity, it must be removable. But this is not necessarily the case for non-isolated singularities.
The famous disck algebra consists of all functions that are analytic over $D$ and continuous over $\overline{D}$. The set is far more than just functions that are analytic over (an open set that contains) $\overline{D}$.

The long estimation of $S$ using $S_1$, $S_2$ is correct, but typing and following it is not simple, so why not apply the same process directly on the given series in the following way for a $z\in \Bbb C$ of modulus one?
$$
\left|\sum_{n\ge 1}\frac{z^n}{n^2}\right|
\le
\sum_{n\ge 1}\left|\frac{z^n}{n^2}\right|
=
\sum_{n\ge 1}\frac 1{n^2}
=\frac16\pi^2\ .
$$
For the second question, regarding singularities on the unit circle, there must be some singularity, since the radius of convergence is one. And indeed, the given function is the complex dilogarithm $\operatorname{Li}_2$,
it has a singularity at $1$. We can understand this also as follows. Assume that $a$ is a point in the interior of a disk where the given function $f=\operatorname{Li}_2$ is analytic, and where the given power series expansion works. Then we can build the derivative, and we have:
$$
f'(z)=
\sum_{n\ge 1}\frac{z^{n-1}}n
=\frac 1z
\sum_{n\ge 1}\frac{z^n}n
=-\frac 1z\log(1-z)\ .
$$
The derivative is also analytic at $a$.
And there is a unique continuation, so regular points of $f$ in $\Bbb C$ are regular points for the analytic continuation of $f'$, which is $z\to-\frac 1z\log(1-z)$.
So $a$ cannot be $1$, since there $f'$ has a logarithmic singularity.
